# Is there a file that contain the network load on linux?

Tags: linux, networking

I'am actually searching for a file on linux that contain the network's load/stat.
Where could i find such a file ? I've searched in /proc/net but i hadn't find yet.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/proc/net/dev

From man page:

> **/proc/net/dev**
>   The dev pseudo-file contains network device status information.  This
>   gives the number of received and sent packets, the number of errors
>   and collisions and other basic statistics. These are  used  by  the 
>   ifconfig(8) program to report device status.  The format is:
>
> ```
> Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
>  face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
>     lo: 2776770   11307    0    0    0     0          0         0  2776770   11307    0    0    0     0       0          0
>   eth0: 1215645    2751    0    0    0     0          0         0  1782404    4324    0    0    0   427       0          0
>   ppp0: 1622270    5552    1    0    0     0          0         0   354130    5669    0    0    0     0       0          0
>   tap0:    7714      81    0    0    0     0          0         0     7714      81    0    0    0     0       0          0
> ```

Comment: That's what i was searching for, thanks! I also found some other information in /proc/net/arp , if anyone is interested. But as you say, all information were in the man proc.

Comment: The procfs interfaces are deprecated, JFYI.

Comment: `procfs` is NOT depreciated on linux (freeBSD is I believe a different story, but linux is not freeBSD). There are sections of proc that are duplicated with sysfs; you can see a list with sysctl -a. However, this is not one of them, and if you look at `man 2 sysctl` notice that it is *actually the sysctl() library call that has been depreciated* in favour of the `/proc/sys` interface!

Answer (score 3):

Like, the output of `ip -s link`?